# Export Variable to use in other classes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, export

A small application that manages and displays users should have the possibility to change the data using "CRUD". However, I have to export the variable `u.userID`.

Given the class *"UserManagementPage"*

```
class UserManagementPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {userList: []}
    }

    getUsersData() {

        const hash="whatever"
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}` },
            
            };
        axios
            .get('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data
                console.log(data)
                
                const users = data.map(u =>
                    <div>
                    <p>{u.userID}
                    
                     </p>
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    )

                    this.setState({
                        users
                    })

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getUsersData()
    }

export default UserManagementPage
```

How do I export `u.userID` so that I can reuse it in other classes?

Comment: As the data that you want to access is coming back as part of an async function, you can use the concept of HOC ( Higher Order Component ) to access the data from components. If using hooks then you could extract this into a hook

Comment: Could you please pass me some code or a link with an example ?

Comment: https://frendly.dev/posts/react-fetch-api-using-hoc